# Trackpoint device not available on Lenovo Carbon X1 5th generation

Tags: 16.04, lenovo, thinkpad, 17.04, trackpoint

I just got a X1 5th gen and when I try any flavor of Ubuntu, the Trackpoint device (TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint) does not show up:

```
ubuntu-mate@ubuntu-mate:~$ xinput -list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                  id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Lenovo Laser Wireless Mouse                 id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                  id=12    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                       id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard                 id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                                id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                   id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Sleep Button                                id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Integrated Camera                           id=10    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard                id=11    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                      id=13    [slave  keyboard (3)]
ubuntu-mate@ubuntu-mate:~$
```

The trackpoint works fine under Windows so I know the hardware is OK.  Things I have done to troubleshoot are:

- Upgraded bios to 1.2
- Tried with ubuntu-mate 16.04, xbuntu 16.04, 17.04, arch (latest), ubuntu-budgie 17.04 -- all have the same problem.
- Tried running from USB or installing on hard disk
- ubuntu versions using UEFI bios, arch used legacy bios
- disabled and enabled the trackpad - no difference
- enabled and disabled intel virtual machine options in bios
- compared with my older thinkpad that works fine and see that no trackpoint device shows up in `/sys/devices/platform/i8042` or in `/dev/input` while they do show up in my older thinkpad.

Any ideas on how to get Linux to see/create the trackpoint device?

Comment: I ran dmidecode 3.0 and the trackpoint does show up:Handle 0x0031, DMI type 21, 7 bytes
Built-in Pointing Device
 Type: Track Point
 Interface: PS/2
 Buttons: 3

Handle 0x0032, DMI type 21, 7 bytes
Built-in Pointing Device
 Type: Touch Pad
 Interface: PS/2
 Buttons: 2

Comment: modprobe psmouse bare, imps, exps make no difference

Comment: Ok modprobe proto=bare does work - it sets up a generic mouse device, but at least it works  Now to fine tune it.

Comment: Would you mind posting exactly what you did to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I run Xubuntu and was able to workaround the problem by:

- disabling the trackpad in the BIOS (I only use the track point)
- editing `/etc/default/grub` to have the line:

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash psmouse.proto=bare"
  ```

More information can be found [here on the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TrackPoint).

Comment: Above works only if I disable trackpoint and trackpad. I only use trackpad, not trackpoint not essential for me, might be a way of enabling trackpoint

Comment: my change was GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash psmouse.synaptics_intertouch=1"

Answer (score 1):

Funny:
I disabled the trackPOINT in the bios and now my trackPAD runs fine for some months now.
No changes in /etc/default/grub were necessary.

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS / Kernel 4.13