# Lenovo Carbon X1 5th gen trackpad not working

Tags: dual-boot, mouse, touchpad, lenovo

I am trying to install ubuntu in a dual boot setup, in parallel with Win 10.
Ubuntu was ok, except that the trackpad did not work.
I saw that kubuntu might handle better some hardware. It doesn't work either.

The track pad buttons have no effect whatsoever. The touchpad in itself seems to do something. If I move my finger all around, from time to time, the mouse pointer will move once. But that's pretty much it.

The following post suggests disabling the trackpad in the BIOS:
[Trackpoint device not available on Lenovo Carbon X1 5th generation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/924492/trackpoint-device-not-available-on-lenovo-carbon-x1-5th-generation)
This works, I can move the pointer around. However:
 - clicks don't work (any of them: trackpad, buttons)
 - now of course it doesn't work any more under Windows.
So this is not a solution.

Another post suggests trying:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

This has no effect.

I have run the following commands, hoping this can help in debugging things:

```
$ xinput -list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech K400                             id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech M510                             id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Keyboard Consumer Control    id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated IR Camera: Integrate           id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Keyboard                     id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Keyboard System Control      id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech K400                             id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Keyboard Consumer Control    id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I tried a few other things: Changing the grub configuration to use:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.nopnp"
```

No effect. Also tried to blacklist i2c_hid, no effect.

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: By the way, all this is trying to use an LTS release, 18.04. Should I target a more recent release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, using Pop!_OS . Moving to 19.04 fixed it for me, you might want to try that.

Comment: I actually tried it this morning, and it indeed worked. Thanks!